# Getting type mismatch exception in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Hi I am trying UDAF with spark scala. I am getting the following exception.

```
 Description Resource Path Location Type type mismatch;  found   : scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Any]  required: String SumCalc.scala   /filter line 63 Scala Problem
```

This is my code.

```
override def evaluate(buffer: Row): Any = {
val in_array = buffer.getAs[WrappedArray[String]](0);
var finalArray = Array.empty[Array[String]]
import scala.util.control.Breaks._
breakable {
  for (outerArray <- in_array) {
          val currentTimeStamp = outerArray(1).toLong 
    var sum = 0.0
    var count = 0
    var check = false
    var list = outerArray
    for (array <- in_array) {
      val toCheckTimeStamp = array(1).toLong
      if (((currentTimeStamp - 10L) <= toCheckTimeStamp) && (currentTimeStamp >= toCheckTimeStamp)) {
        sum += array(5).toDouble 
        count += 1
      }
      if ((currentTimeStamp - 10L) > toCheckTimeStamp) {
        check = true
        break
      }
    }
    if (sum != 0.0 && check) list = list :+ (sum).toString // getting error on this line.
        else list = list :+ list(5).toDouble.toString 
    finalArray ++= Array(list)
  }
  finalArray
}
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think your code does not make sense. `outerArray` is a String (and so is `list`), `array` is a String too. If that is what you want, then you must concatenate using `+` instead of `:+` (also in the line below). In addition, you should give more meaningful names to your variables

Comment: And your finalArray is of type Array[Array[String]] and you are adding Array[String] to it as list is a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of mistakes in your `evaluate` function of `UDAF`.

1. `list` variable is a `string` but you are treating it as an `array`
2. `finalArray` is initialized as `Array.empty[Array[String]]` but later on you are adding `Array(list)` to the `finalArray`
3. You are not returning `finalArray` from `evaluate` method as its inside `for` loop

So the correct way should be as below

```
  override def evaluate(buffer: Row): Any = {
    val in_array = buffer.getAs[WrappedArray[String]](0);
    var finalArray = Array.empty[String]
    import scala.util.control.Breaks._
    breakable {
      for (outerArray <- in_array) {
        val currentTimeStamp = outerArray(1).toLong // timestamp values
        var sum = 0.0
        var count = 0
        var check = false
        var list = outerArray
        for (array <- in_array) {
          val toCheckTimeStamp = array(1).toLong
          if (((currentTimeStamp - 10L) <= toCheckTimeStamp) && (currentTimeStamp >= toCheckTimeStamp)) {
            sum += array(5).toDouble // RSSI weightage values
            count += 1
          }
          if ((currentTimeStamp - 10L) > toCheckTimeStamp) {
            check = true
            break
          }
        }

        if (sum != 0.0 && check) list = list + (sum).toString // calculate sum for the 10 secs difference
        else list = list + (sum).toString // If 10 secs difference is not there take rssi weightage value

        finalArray ++= Array(list)
      }
    }
    finalArray // Final results for this function
  }
```

Hope the answer is helpful